# Only 1 textbox will populate with parameters passed from another form. Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

I have a form ***frmControlSystem*** that connects to an exterior data source from which I receive strings that go into an array. This form opens another form ***frmResult_Vote*** to display that information.
The 2nd form is passed the string array as a parameter along with an integer of how many items to display and one other parameter. This 2nd form will properly enable the .Visible for the needed textBoxes. but only the first textBox will actually show text in it; the others are blank.

The first form uses this code to display the 2nd form:

```
frmResult_Vote results = new frmResult_Vote(memberDisplayName, iMemberQty, ConstMembersPlusOne);
results.Show()
```

The second form creates an array of textBoxes so I can loop and make visible only the ones that I want to use as well as populating the .Text attribute. This code is:

```
public frmResult_Vote(string[] myVoteMembers, int iMemberQty, int ConstMembersPlusOne)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = "FU";

            TextBox[] memberTextBoxes = new TextBox[ConstMembersPlusOne];

            memberTextBoxes[1] = txtDisplayName1; memberTextBoxes[2] = txtDisplayName2; memberTextBoxes[3] = txtDisplayName3; memberTextBoxes[4] = txtDisplayName4;
            memberTextBoxes[5] = txtDisplayName5; memberTextBoxes[6] = txtDisplayName6; memberTextBoxes[7] = txtDisplayName7; memberTextBoxes[8] = txtDisplayName8;
            memberTextBoxes[9] = txtDisplayName9; memberTextBoxes[10] = txtDisplayName10; memberTextBoxes[11] = txtDisplayName11; memberTextBoxes[12] = txtDisplayName12;

            for (int i = 1; i <= iMemberQty; i++)
            {
                memberTextBoxes[i].Text = myVoteMembers[i];
                memberTextBoxes[i].Visible = true;
            }            
        }
```

When the 2nd form displays, the proper quantity of textBoxes will enable, but only the first one will show text.

The second form has 12 textBoxes on it named txtDisplayName1 thru txtDisplayName12. These are what I am using to populate the TextBox array.

Last bits of oddity (at least to me): Every other textBox on the second form was drawn with a different BackColor. That never shows when the first form show() the second form; they all show with the color of white.

In trying to get *something* to show in the other textBoxes, I have also tried to specifically call by the non-array names like this:

```
txtDisplayName1.Text = myVoteMembers[1];
```

This didn't do anything at all.

I have also placed a random textBox on the second form and tried to populate it with this line:

```
textBox1.Text = "FU";
```

that textBox also would not populate... but if I comment out the for loop, that textBox1.Text assignment will work. It is called before everything else, as well.

I have verified that the array myVoteMembers has strings in it and when I step through the code I can see the assignment happening here:

```
memberTextBoxes[i].Text = myVoteMembers[i];
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Logically nothing seems to be wrong. Can you check if myVoteMembers has proper data. If there is any exception being thrown in the for loop. If you can share a minimum reproducible example, we can help better.

Comment: This is a simple garden variety debugging issue, and this is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug your code using the **[free, awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

You have an exception - possibly here:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= iMemberQty; i++)
{
     memberTextBoxes[i].Text = myVoteMembers[i];
     memberTextBoxes[i].Visible = true;
}
```

myVoteMembers array will start from 0 and have iMemberQty number of items. Which means 0-iMemberQty-1 indexes. While you are accessing iMemberQty'th index which throws Index out of Bound Exception

Comment: I understand that the array is 0 based and my source data is 1 based. My array is set to maximum+1 so that I am referencing it as a 1 based element. 
In my code, array[0] is not used or referenced,
The debugger is not showing any exceptions being thrown while trying to populate the textBox.Text array

Also strange is that textBox1.Text will not populate with text while the for loop is present, even though there is nothing that connects them together.

Comment: If myVoteMembers array is iMemberQty+1 size - then there is no problem with your code at all (I recreated locally) and it works. May be there's something elsewhere that is wrong.

Comment: I converted it over to a 0-based code and I still have the same results.
I have also added labels in addition to the textBox to try and see if there is any different results. The label autoSize attribute was left at True. When I run the code, I still do not see the text, but the labels are growing to accommodate the text that should be there; but I still cannot see the text. I have added code to explicitly set the ForeColor of the label but I still cannot read the text... but it appears that it is being sent based on the label fields growing to accommodate the text being sent.

Comment: Debug the loop. Do you see the value being set on Text property? May be add a break statement at the end of loop so it just exists after 1st iteration. Does that make text appear? There definetly is something wrong at other place while you are looking for it in wrong place.

Comment: Last advice I can give is, may be upload code to github/sourceforge and share link so that we can debug your project.